# Replication Reinitialization from backup

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have Reinitialization transactional replication of 950 GB database from backup. It is working fine.

I left allow_anonymous & immediate_sync 1 i.e true. I plan to keep it as true.

Is that fine or do I need to change to false.
I have tried to put false, it is making lot of blocking in the published database.

Please advise.

Comment: What dbms are you referring to?  Add it as a tag.

Comment: I have added  it is MSSQL